# What is the difference between a GPU with 1x 16GB vs 2x 8GB VRAM?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

My employer asked me to choose a graphic card for deep learning purposes like NLP and vision domains.

What is the difference between a graphic card with say 16 GB vs 2x 8GB VRAM on same hardware, regardless of its cost?

##### I mean, instead of using one GPU with 16 GB VRAM, we use two GPUs with 8 GB VRAM each.

My employer wants to see if there are no significant differences, it would be better for them to buy to GPU to use in multiple hardware for future purposes.

Comment: If a computer or video card has 16 GB of memory, then it has 16 GB of memory, it does not matter how many memory modules it has.  The performance will be identical outside of a benchmark.  You are unlikely to find a graphic card where it will be advertised as "16 GDDR5" vs "2x8GB GDDR5" as latter is not typical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know 2x8GB is not common. but someone may want to use these GPUs in separate hardware, I think this is the main issue of my employer.

Comment: @MohamadaliMahmoodpour can you clarify... are you asking about 1x PCIe Graphics card with 16 GB VRAM, vs 2x PCIe Graphics cards with 8 GB VRAM each? (unlikely to be asking about memory ICs, as cards will generally have 4-8 or more)

Comment: @Attie Yes, I mean exactly what you said

Comment: @MohamadaliMahmoodpour - You should edit your question to reflect that fact, there is a significant difference between what you asked, and what you have now explained.

Comment: Can the software you are using work with 2x video cards? you are not just doubling the ram, you are also doubling the GPUs.

Comment: I am doubling the number of gpus but halving the VRAM.

Answer (score 0):

If your workload requires more than 8GB of VRAM for optimal performance, you'll see significant performance loss as the GPU(s) need to swap to system RAM or storage.

If your workload uses 8GB or less of VRAM **and** is capable of scaling across multiple GPUs, then two GPUs could net up to twice the performance. If your application doesn't scale and isn't capable of running multiple instances, your performance won't be uplifted unless there are other workloads that can be offloaded to the second GPU.

Outside of a sideband solution like NVLINK, multiple GPUs are generally unable to share memory. I'm unaware of any 8GB GPU that supports NVLINK, so it is unlikely to be a factor for consideration, but be aware that NVLINK is a high-speed interconnect for GPUs and the application must be developed to take advantage of it - it’s not an automatic VRAM doubler.